# UIBarButtonItem not showing up on UIToolbar Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigation controller with the toolbar enabled.I have a view controller with an MKMapView that is embedded in the navigation controller. When I run it in the simulator the toolbar shows up. However, when I try to add a UIBarButtonItem from code, the UIBarButtonItem doesn't show up on the toolbar. To add the button I have the following code in my viewDidAppear method:

```
var trackingButton:MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem = MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem(mapView: self.theMapView)
    self.navigationController?.toolbarItems?.append(trackingButton)
    //self.toolbarItems?.append(trackingButton) also doesn't work
```

Any Ideas on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is intended functionality. According to the docs:

> The custom toolbar associated with the navigation controller.
>   (read-only)
>
> This property contains a reference to the built-in toolbar managed by
>   the navigation controller. Access to this toolbar is provided solely
>   for clients that want to present an action sheet from the toolbar. You
>   should not modify the UIToolbar object directly. Management of this
>   toolbar’s contents is done through the custom view controllers
>   associated with this navigation controller. For each view controller
>   on the navigation stack, you can assign a custom set of toolbar items
>   using the setToolbarItems:animated: method of UIViewController.
>
> The visibility of this toolbar is controlled by the toolbarHidden
>   property. The toolbar also obeys the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property
>   of the currently visible view controller and hides and shows itself
>   automatically as needed.

In other words, you can't do `navigationController.toolbar.setItems`. You have to use the navigationControllers methods (i.e): `navigationController.setToolbarItems`